# Why do I get permission denied when using unshare?

Tags: linux-kernel, namespace, capabilities

I'm exploring the namespace feature of linux kernel, using Archlinux. But I got some message that I can't explain the reason, could anyone explain them to me?

```
xtricman⚓ArchVirtual⏺️~export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
xtricman⚓ArchVirtual⏺️~unshare --propagation private -r bash
Could not get property: Access denied
root⚓⏺️~mount -o remount,ro /
mount: /: permission denied.
```

Based on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_Containers#An_example_to_illustrate_unprivileged_containers), I CAN create an user namespace using my normal account, and I do, but Why do I get the `Could not get property: Access denied` message?

Based on [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html), Newly created bash process has full capability in the new namespace, so why do I get the "permission denied" message when I tried to do mount? Is there anything related with file capability? How can I check the current capabilities the current bash process have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are trying to run would change the root filesystem to read-only.  It would affect outside the namespace as well.  So you do not have permission.

You only want to change one specific mount, the mount inside the namespace.  Use this command:

```
mount -o remount,bind,ro /
```

Comment: Why? Shouldn't the new shell run in a separate mount namespace? What does the bind and remount in the same mount command in your answer mean?

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 there is only one instance of the filesystem.  (This is sometimes referred to as a superblock).  Otherwise, how would a mount option like `journal_dev=` work?  The `ro` option applies to the underlying filesystem, unless `bind` is passed in the same command.

Comment: I said, mount namespace, not filesystem, shouldn't it be  completely another mount, although the mounted filesystem is the same one? Shouldn't read-only a property of a mount instead of a filesystem?

Comment: Did you mean people are not able to create two mounts for the same filesystem, one is rw and another is ro?

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 the root mount inside the namespace is exactly equivalent to a bind mount of the root outside the namespace. And bind mounts can be made readonly without making the original readonly.  But, also know that the kernel does not keep any track of which mount is a bind mount and which mount was "original".  Hence you can do `remount,bind,...` on *any* mount.

Comment: OK, it seems to be the strange behavior of mount command.  ro argument for command line could be interpreted as `data` argument "ro", or MS_RDONLY as `mountflags`, depending on whether bind is specified from the command line. The former is per-superblock option while the latter is per-mount option. The command in the question just triggered the former case, which needs CAP_SYS_ADMIN in the top-level user namespace.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 not exactly.  The kernel interprets MS_RDONLY differently depending on whether MS_BIND is passed.  Internally the kernel has separate flags SB_RDONLY and MNT_RDONLY, and if MS_BIND is passed then it does not change the superblock flag.  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/fs/namespace.c